# How to send search term and retrieve the information from a website using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to search a list of more than a thousand different drugs on this website (http://www.commonchemistry.org/), then get the CAS number for each drug.

I looked up the 'httr' package, but I have no experience in web scraping. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `search.aspx` with a search term and look for the right element in the HTML - using the `rvest` package:

```
> library(rvest)
> h = read_html("http://www.commonchemistry.org//search.aspx?terms=paracetamol")
> html_text(html_node(h,"#registryNumberLabel"))
[1] "103-90-2"
```

Works for "aspirin" and "paracetamol", but "viagra" returns NA because its not found. Other things might happen.

Add `&exact=true` to do an exact match on the search term, otherwise you might get multiple matches in a slightly different format page.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I'm looking for!!